# How to put content into layout

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a layout from https://www.layoutit.com/grid#clear for my webpage.
[image: Here's an image how it looks like]

But I want to remove these texts in the center of those boxes.I tried somethings but didn't work unfortunately.Here's what I tried

```css
html, body { margin: 15; height: 100% } 
.grid-container * {  }
.grid-container div:after {
    content: attr(class);
    color: #888;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #2A2A2A;
}
.grid-container {  display: grid;  height: 100%;  
                   grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr; 
                   grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr; 
                   grid-gap: 10px 10px;  
                   grid-template-areas: 'box1 box1 box2 box2 box3 box4' 'box5 box5 box6 box6 box6 box7' 'box5 box5 box6 box6 box6 box8' 'box9 box10 box11 box12 box13 box14';}
.box1 { grid-area: box1; 
        
}
.box2 { grid-area: box2; }
.box3 { grid-area: box3; }
.box4 { grid-area: box4; }
.box5 { grid-area: box5; }
.box6 { grid-area: box6; }
.box7 { grid-area: box7; }
.box8 { grid-area: box8; }
.box9 { grid-area: box9; }
.box10 { grid-area: box10; }
.box11 { grid-area: box11; }
.box12 { grid-area: box12; }
.box13 { grid-area: box13; }
.box14 { grid-area: box14; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>New Pen!</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body body bgcolor="black">
    <div class='grid-container'>
        <div class='box1'></div>
        <div class='box2'></div>
        <div class='box3'></div>
        <div class='box4'></div>
        <div class='box5'></div>
        <div class='box6'></div>
        <div class='box7'></div>
        <div class='box8'></div>
        <div class='box9'></div>
        <div class='box10'></div>
        <div class='box11'></div>
        <div class='box12'></div>
        <div class='box13'></div>
        <div class='box14'></div>
    </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

I tried also put the names into the divs but it doesnt work.Instead of names I will put some contents inside of these boxes.I am not allowed to change the box content and I cant understand where those names written(box1,box2,box3 )

Answer (score 5):

The [**attr**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr) will grab the attribute from the relevant dom & in this case will add it in the content.

Replace with `content: attr(class);` with `content: '';`

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 15;
  height: 100%
}

.grid-container * {}

.grid-container div:after {
  content: '';
  color: #888;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #2A2A2A;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px 10px;
  grid-template-areas: 'box1 box1 box2 box2 box3 box4' 'box5 box5 box6 box6 box6 box7' 'box5 box5 box6 box6 box6 box8' 'box9 box10 box11 box12 box13 box14';
}

.box1 {
  grid-area: box1;
}

.box2 {
  grid-area: box2;
}

.box3 {
  grid-area: box3;
}

.box4 {
  grid-area: box4;
}

.box5 {
  grid-area: box5;
}

.box6 {
  grid-area: box6;
}

.box7 {
  grid-area: box7;
}

.box8 {
  grid-area: box8;
}

.box9 {
  grid-area: box9;
}

.box10 {
  grid-area: box10;
}

.box11 {
  grid-area: box11;
}

.box12 {
  grid-area: box12;
}

.box13 {
  grid-area: box13;
}

.box14 {
  grid-area: box14;
}
```

```html
<body body bgcolor="black">
  <div class='grid-container'>
    <div class='box1'></div>
    <div class='box2'></div>
    <div class='box3'></div>
    <div class='box4'></div>
    <div class='box5'></div>
    <div class='box6'></div>
    <div class='box7'></div>
    <div class='box8'></div>
    <div class='box9'></div>
    <div class='box10'></div>
    <div class='box11'></div>
    <div class='box12'></div>
    <div class='box13'></div>
    <div class='box14'></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: ohh yeah you're right. It needs the empty value in order to show up

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove `content: attr(class);` in your class `.grid-container`. Be aware that the structure might collapse if you haven't specified a height and width of the elements.

```
.grid-container div:after {
    content: attr(class); /* <-- This one */
    color: #888;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #2A2A2A;
}
```

This attribute can be used to specify what content to be in the specific container. Most used for text or to change text on hover. In this case it shows the name of the class used.

Comment: This line needs to be there in order for the `:after` pseudo element to appear. If it's removed, nothing will show